# Dojo + DataGrid + JsonRest + custom json

Tags: json, rest, datagrid, dojo

I have following problem. My REST web service returns json like this one:

{"response":{"headers":"","items":{"item":[{"@id":"1","email":"admin@admin","firstname":"admin","lastname":"admin","login":"admin"},{"@id":"2","email":"Bennett@Tawney.com","firstname":"Bennett","lastname":"Tawney","login":"bennettabcd"}...

How can I force DataGrid to display items from json above? I can't change REST web service, it must return jsons in this format. Http request is ok and server returns my json, but datagrid is not filled in. **Do you have any idea?**

My "dojo" code is below:

```
        var store = new Cache(new JsonRest({
            target: settings.vars.API_URL + "/frapi/users/load",
            start: page * rows,
                count: 10,
                sort: [
                    {attribute: "id", descending: true}
                ],
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                }
        }), Memory());

        grid = new DataGrid({
            store: new ObjectStore({objectStore: store}),
            queryOptions: {},
            structure:[{
                defaultCell: {
                    width: "auto"
                },
                cells: [
                    {name: "Id", field: "id", width: "50px"},
                    {name: "Login", field: "login"},
                    {name: "Email", field: "email", width: "200px"},
                    {name: "Firstname", field: "firstname"},
                    {name: "Lastname", field: "lastname"}
                ]
            }]            
        }, "grid");

        grid.startup();
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found solution. Please see code below:

```
    var extractItemsFromResponse = function(deferred) {
        return deferred.then(function(response) {
            return response.response.items.item;
        });
    };

    aspect.after(store, "query", extractItemsFromResponse);
```

I hope it'll help you.